# Image with overlay captions

Tags: html, css, image

I have a problem with image descriptions. I have HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="scrollable-content" data-mcs-theme="dark-thick" style="padding: 0px; overflow-x: auto;">
    <ul style="list-style: none; white-space:nowrap; padding: 0px;">
        @foreach($projects as $project)
            <li style="display: inline; margin: 0px;">
                <a href="{!! url($locale.'/projects/project/'.$project->id) !!}">
                    <img class="project-cover-image" src="/images/{!! $project->cover_image_name !!}" height="250px" width="auto">
                </a>
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
</div>
```

It creates a nice looking gallery with horizontal scrollbar. But I need to add descriptions to images that will be placed at the bottom of the pictures covering whole their widths and they should have to be transparent to some degree.

The problem is, whatever I do, I either get description that takes 100% `width` of the page, or it has `width` of the text inside it.

I have tried doing it with `div`, `span`, different combinations of `position absolute/relative`, everything and I couldn't manage to make it work.

It should look something like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: use inline-block for li instead inline. it will allow you to set size or not, margin, padding ... and off course the relative/absolute combination will work better

Answer (score 1):

use `position:relative/absolute`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.scrollable-content {
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: auto
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0;
  margin:0
}
li {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block
}
span {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%
}
img {
  display: block
}
a {
  color: #fff
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable-content" data-mcs-theme="dark-thick">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <img class="project-cover-image" src="//lorempixel.com/250/250">
        <span>description</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <img class="project-cover-image" src="//lorempixel.com/500/250">
        <span>description</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <img class="project-cover-image" src="//lorempixel.com/400/250">
        <span>description</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That would work, but i need to leave out the li width because there are images of different sizes in my gallery. And also, doing it in this way would break my horizontal gallery with scrollbar.

Comment: @user3476085 this answers your issue with width of description. li relative, span absolute that can then take width:100%;

Comment: This is how it looks: http://picresize.com/popup.html?images/rsz_screenshot_from_2016-03-07_02-20-54.jpg

Comment: I did show you all the code relevant to the problem.

Comment: @user3476085 updated answer with different `width`s, take a look

Answer (score 1):

You have two options (wich produce the same result):

**1**- A div with a image as background, and a subtitle inside this div;

```css
#image {
  width:550px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/HNj6tRD.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}

.coverdown {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
<div class="coverdown">Subtitle here with a description.</div>
</div>
```

**2**- The image and a subtitle with `position:absolute` inside a `position:relative` container;

```css
#container {
  width:550px;
  height:150px;
  position:relative;
}

img {
  width:550px;
  height:150px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}

.subtitle {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/HNj6tRD.jpg" alt=img>
<div class="subtitle">Subtitle here with a description.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: drop the background idea where image are content, you should use figure an figcaption if you propose to rewrite OP html ;)

Answer (score 0):

basicly, you need relative/absolute as @dippas's answer.

as I advised, use `inline-block`, so it gets sized by content and will allow easily to `position` your description.

example below with `figure` and `figcaption`.

`figure` can be wrap in a `<a>`link displayed `inline-block` and `figure` as a `block` then to avoid a gap underneath.

```css
figure {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  display: block;
  max-height:80vh;height:250px/*snippet demo purpose */
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* makeup*/
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  
  
}
/* demo purpose */

div {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:auto;
}
figure {
  white-space: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://www.hyperkreeytiv.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/IMG_4973.jpg" alt="wolves" />
    <figcaption>
      <p>these are wolves</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-oSEWgZNEopE/TtL8kfGuBzI/AAAAAAAAB6U/b8VSzZaoK3g/s400/action_wolf_1111_photo1.jpg" alt="wolves" />
    <figcaption>
      <p>these are wolves</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GfOyrk3kZ0w/TewM0BMvbNI/AAAAAAAABM0/KPm3li5Xwko/s1600/alpha+male+Wallpaper__yvt2.jpg" alt="wolves" />
    <figcaption>
      <p>these are wolves</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://www.ooyuz.com/images/2015/10/13/1447449028465.jpg" alt="wolves" />
    <figcaption>
      <p>these are wolves</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```